# How to get a diff from python's `mock.assert_called_with()`?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-unittest, python-mock

When calling `unittest.TestCase.assertEqual()` on two complex dictionaries, I get a nice diff.

Is there any way to get a diff from Python 2.7's `mock.Mock.assert_called_with`? I'm testing calls that take some dict parameters with complex values, and it's very difficult to see what the problem is when one of them is just missing a boolean.

e.g.

```
AssertionError: Expected call: post('http://cloud-atlas.cogolo.net/api/executions', auth=('cloudatlas', 'cloudatlas'), data={'environment': 'hadoop', 'source': 'repo', 'output_path': 'hdfs://namenode-01/user/erose/testing', 'production': True, 'input_path': 'hdfs://namenode-01/foo/bar', 'name': 'linecount', 'mrcloud_options': '{"mrcloud_option_A": "foobar", "hadoop_user_name": "erose"}', 'details': '{"path_to_file": "linecount.py", "parameters": {}, "branch": "master", "repo_name": "example_repo"}'}, headers={'X-COGO-CLOUDATLAS-USER': 'erose'})
Actual call: post('http://cloud-atlas.cogolo.net/api/executions', auth=('cloudatlas', 'cloudatlas'), data={'input_path': 'hdfs://namenode-01/foo/bar', 'name': 'linecount', 'environment': 'hadoop', 'source': 'repo', 'output_path': 'hdfs://namenode-01/user/erose/testing', 'details': '{"path_to_file": "linecount.py", "parameters": {}, "branch": "master", "repo_name": "example_repo"}', 'mrcloud_options': '{"mrcloud_option_A": "foobar", "hadoop_user_name": "erose"}'}, headers={'X-COGO-CLOUDATLAS-USER': 'erose'})
```

Comment: I'm not aware of any 'easy' way to do so; you'd have to patch the [`Mock._format_mock_failure_message()` function](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.5/Lib/unittest/mock.py#l737).

Comment: Dang. Thanks. Since `mock` is built-in in python 3, would pull requests against it have to go through a PEP?

Comment: No; just submit a request at bugs.python.org

Comment: Sadly this still hasn't been implemented. Future visitors may consider the option doing assert_called() instead, followed by assertDictEqual on the complex dictionary (obtained from call_args). You could even finish with the assert_called_with to check the remaining of the arguments. A bit messy, but this should at least produce useful output every time.

Answer (score 0):

Without an official support for a diff output from `Mock.assert_called_with`, you can implement the logics on your own with a `Mock` subclass by overriding the `assert_called_with` method with assertions that a call was made, and that `args` and `kwargs` are as given, taking advantage of the nicely diff'd output of the `assertTupleEqual` and `assertDictEqual` methods of a dummy `TestCase`:

```
from unittest import mock, TestCase

class CallDiffingMock(mock.Mock):
    def assert_called_with(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.assert_called()
        test = TestCase()
        test.assertTupleEqual(args, self.call_args.args)
        test.assertDictEqual(kwargs, self.call_args.kwargs)
```

so that:

```
class Test(TestCase):
    def test_call(self):
        f = CallDiffingMock()
        f(a=1, b=2)
        f.assert_called_with(a=1, b=2, c=3)
```

would produce:

```
======================================================================
FAIL: test_call (main.Test.test_call)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 14, in test_call
    f.assert_called_with(a=1, b=2, c=3)
  File "main.py", line 8, in assert_called_with
    test.assertDictEqual(kwargs, self.call_args.kwargs)
AssertionError: {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3} != {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
- {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
?                --------

+ {'a': 1, 'b': 2}

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.003s

FAILED (failures=1)
```

Demo: https://ideone.com/OvfWY8